# how to read binary format byte by byte in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fread

I have been struggling with this bug. When using MATLAB to read a binary file that contains three columns of numbers in `float` formats.

I am reading one number at a time using this line.

```
    pt(j) = fread(fid,1,'float','a');
```

I have found that sometimes (rarely) `MATLAB` instead of reading four bytes for a float, it uses 5 bytes. And it misses up the rest of the reading. I am not sure if the file is corrupted or `MATLAB` has a bug there. When I printed the file as a txt and read it in txt everything works well.

As a work around here is what I did:

```
cur = ftell(fid);
if (cur - prev)~= 4
      pt(j) = 0; % I m throwing this reading away for the sake of saving the rest of the data. This is not ideal 
      cur = prev +4;
      fseek(fid, cur,'bof');
end
prev = cur;
```

I tried different combinations of different formats `float32` `float64` etc... nothing works `MATLAB` always read 5 bytes instead of 4 at this particular location.

EDIT:
To solve it based on Chris's answer. I was using this command to open the file.

```
fid = fopen(fname,'rt');
```

I replaced it with this

```
fid = fopen(fname,'r');
```

Comment: Shouldn't your reading staement be `pt(j) = fread(fid,1,'float',0,'a');`. In your original statement, your variable `a` is in place of the [`skip`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html#btp1twt-1-skip) parameter ...

Comment: @Hoki Nope, skip is optional. It does not matter.

Comment: I think I know what is going on here (certain enough to post an answer). But  you might want to include how you open the file in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes, rarely, skipping a byte. It sounds to me like you are on Windows, and have opened the file in text mode. See [the `permissions` parameter to the `fopen` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#btrnibn-1-permission).

When opening a file in text mode on Windows, the sequence `\r\n` (13,10) is replaced with `\n` (10). This happens before `fread` gets to it.

So, when opening the file, don't do:

```
fid = fopen('name', 'rt');
```

The `t` here indicates "text". Instead, do:

```
fid = fopen('name', 'r');
```

To make this explicit, you can add `b` to the permissions. This is not documented, but is supposed to mean "binary", and makes the call similar to what you'd do in C or in the POSIX `fopen()`:

```
fid = fopen('name', 'rb');
```

Comment: wow, you are a champ Sir. It works. I was using 'rt' exactly like you described it. When I removed the 't'. It works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @Samer ... I would also recommend to follow his last advice, make the binary format explicit by using `rb`.